# Is it possible for a character at any level to cast all 44 Cantrips in one week without Magic Items?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, cantrips, time

As a DM, I enjoy [metaphorically] playing with fire.

For *no particular reason*, I am considering introducing the following Rite to my campaign:

> **Rites of Destruction.** When the world was created, the Gods left in a secret power that could be used to completely destroy the universe instantaneously, and remake it with new parameters at the whim of whomever used this power (after which the power then leaves them).
>
> Although intended only for use by the gods, this power can be attained and used by any mortal that, within a span of one week, casts every single Cantrip in existence using their own spellcasting abilities (i.e. no Magic Items) in a specific, secret ordering.

Setting aside the improbability of a player correctly guessing the exact order of Cantrips to cast with no assistance from me, the DM, is it even possible for a single correctly-built character to cast all 44 Cantrips (27 from the Player's Handbook, 12 from Xanathar's Guide to Everything, 4 from Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, and 1 from Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica) at all, within the span of a seven day week?

In my campaign, I permit the 2019 revision of the Artificer Unearthed Arcana, so for the purposes of this question, it is a valid class a character can take to try to obtain all the cantrips they need. Also, any Cantrips a Warlock is able to cast are valid unless they are acquired through the *Pact of the Tome* feature.

Furthermore, while using the Spell Duplication features of *Wish* is perfectly fine, using *Wish* to wish for "I want to know how to cast all cantrips" would definitely be twisted with so as to render this Rite inoperable by the person making that wish, so it's not a solution to this particular issue.

Comment: What is a rite for the purpose of this question?

Comment: @QPaul A keyword that, to my knowledge, doesn't have preexisting convention in 5th Edition D&D.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Polymorph is allowed, although to my knowledge, *Polymorph* does not permit a character access to the creature's spellcasting abilities.

Comment: [This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88219/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-cantrips-you-can-get-by-20th-level) might help.

Comment: Are magic items created with character abilities valid? Are all official books available?

Comment: @Szega Magic Items are invalid, regardless of their source. All officially published 5e books are valid, along with the aforementioned 2019 Artificer revision.

Comment: Is there a limit to epic boons granted?

Comment: Is there a limit to changing planes during the process?

Comment: What happens when a new book comes out?

Comment: After the release of Explorer's Guide to Wildemount and Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, there are now two more cantrips to add to your list: Sapping Sting (for chronurgy and graviturgy wizards) and Mind Sliver (for sorcerers, warlocks, and wizards).

Answer (score 47):

## Disclaimer

This answer was written assuming *Encode Thoughts* was on the Wizard Spell List. While DNDBeyond lists the spell as a Wizard Spell, the Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica book doesn't actually specify that the spell has an associated class. If your table accepts DNDBeyond's wisdom that the spell is indeed a Wizard spell, then this answer is valid, but if not, you'll need to see [my revised answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158676/42386) which I've posted separately.

### We can get there without *Wish*, without Epic Boons

#### The Character

- **Race:** Tiefling (Or High Elf if GGR backgrounds aren't permitted at the table)
- **Background:** Simic Scientist
- **Feats**

  - *Magic Initiate [Druid]*
  - *Spell Sniper [Druid]*
- **Classes**: 18 Levels

  - **Artificer** *[Any Archetype]*: Level 10
  - **Bard**: Level 1
  - **Cleric** *[Arcana]*: Level 1
  - **Druid** *[Land]*: Level 2
  - **Sorcerer** *[Any Archetype]*: Level 1
  - **Warlock** *[Celestial]*: Level 1
  - **Wizard** *[Illusionist]*: Level 2

## Key Points

There's a few critical things we're gaining:

#### The Artificer's *Right Cantrip for the Job* feature

At level 10, an Artificer gains the ability to swap out their Cantrips, one cantrip at a time, per short or long rest. In order to cycle through all 19 Cantrips that an Artificer may prepare, they would need to rest 19 times in 7 days, averaging to about 3 rests per day. That.... is very easily attainable, given 1 long rest and 2 short rests each day.

So far: 19/44 Cantrips

#### Bard/Cleric/Druid/Sorcerer/Warlock/Wizard

The base Cantrips provided by each of these classes will add up:

- Bard: 2
- Cleric: 3
- Druid: 2
- Sorcerer: 4
- Warlock: 2
- Wizard: 3

Total from this group: 16 Cantrips

So far: 35/44 Cantrips

## Archetypes

Some Archetypes of each of these classes will give us some additional Cantrips.

- Arcana Cleric: 2 Cantrips (from the Wizard Spell List)
- Land Druid: 1 Cantrip
- Celestial Warlock: 1 Cantrip—*Sacred Flame*
- Technically this also gives us *Light*, but since that's on the Artificer list already, it's not adding a new cantrip, and can be discarded
- Illusionist Wizard: 1 Cantrip—*Minor Illusion*

From this group: 5 Cantrips

So far: 40/44 Cantrips

## Feats

Two feats give us some extra Cantrips

- *Magic Initiate*: 2 Extra Cantrips. We pick Druid because Druids have the most class-exclusive Cantrips of any class in the game, making it easier to pick up all the cantrips we need.
- *Spell Sniper*: 1 Extra Cantrip (but only Attack-Roll Cantrips). We pick Druid again for the same reason.

From this group: 3 Cantrips

So far: 43/44 Cantrips

## Racial Feature

Many Races offer a Cantrip as a level 1 spellcasting feature. We could have gone with many different races (and see later for why we might have needed to) but Tiefling was my preference, so I went with it.

From this group: 1 Cantrip

So far: 44/44 Cantrips

## Background

Each of the Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica Backgrounds add spells to all of the spell lists that a character has, including 2 or 3 Cantrips.

This doesn't actually increase the number of cantrips we can learn, but it offers us some flexibility in how we allocate the cantrips to each class/feature.

## Spell List (And Sources)

| **Cantrip** | **Source** | **Feature** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acid Splash | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Create Bonfire | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Dancing Lights | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Fire Bolt | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Frostbite | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Guidance | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Light | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Mage Hand | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Magic Stone | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Mending | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Message | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Poison Spray | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Prestidigitation | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Ray of Frost | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Resistance | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Shocking Grasp | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Spare the Dying | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Thorn Whip | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Thunderclap | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Blade Ward | Bard |  |
| Vicious Mockery | Bard |  |
| Gust | Cleric | Arcana |
| Infestation | Cleric | Arcana |
| Toll the Dead | Cleric |  |
| Word of Radiance | Cleric |  |
| Druidcraft | Cleric | Simic Scientist |
| Control Flames | Druid | Circle of Land (Level 2) |
| Primal Savagery | Druid |  |
| Produce Flame | Druid | Spell Sniper |
| Shape Water | Druid |  |
| Shillelagh | Druid | Magic Initiate |
| Mold Earth | Druid | Magic Initiate |
| Booming Blade | Sorcerer |  |
| Chill Touch | Sorcerer |  |
| Friends | Sorcerer |  |
| True Strike | Sorcerer |  |
| Thaumaturgy | Tiefling |  |
| Eldritch Blast | Warlock |  |
| Green-Flame Blade | Warlock |  |
| Sacred Flame | Warlock | Celestial |
| Encode Thoughts | Wizard |  |
| Lightning Lure | Wizard |  |
| Minor Illusion | Wizard | Illusionist (Level 2) |
| Sword Burst | Wizard |  |

## *"But what if the GGR Backgrounds aren't allowed?"*

There's an easy fix. Go with a High Elf instead, and pick *Mold Earth* as your Wizard Cantrip. The Druid then replaces *Mold Earth* with *Druidcraft*, and the Cleric picks up *Thaumaturgy*. Personally, I just like the Tiefling better, so that's what I went with.

Comment: If you allow spell duplication via Wish (which OP has said is allowed), then that gets you 7 extra cantrips which you don't have to know, if you manage to copy a scroll of Wish into your spellbook. This would let you drop one of the classes in which you have 1 level and not use the GGR backgrounds, while remaining a Tiefling.

Comment: @JarredAllen [Multiclassed Wizards can't copy spells that their Wizard levels alone aren't high enough to cast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50426/42386).

Comment: Related: [Can the Encode Thoughts cantrip be acquired outside of the Dimir Operative background?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/171147)

Answer (score 22):

Yes, this can be done.

### The Character

One character, called Celine from here on, who can accomplish this is a level 20 character with the following classes:

- Bard (College of Lore) 18 ---------------- (for Additional Magical Secrets, Magical Secrets, Magic Initiate feat, Spell Sniper feat, and spells)
- Cleric (Nature Domain) 1 -------------------------- (for Acolyte of Nature and spells)
- Warlock (Divine Soul) 1 ------------------ (for Bonus Cantrips and spells)

... and the following Epic Boons:

- Boon of High Magic
- Boon of Spell Recall

### The Cantrips

To start with, Celine knows **22 cantrips** from class features and feats:

- 4 from bard's Spellcasting
- 2 from Additional Magical Secrets
- 5 from Magical Secrets (the other Magical Secret spell is used for *wish*)
- 3 from cleric's Spellcasting
- 1 from Acolyte of Nature
- 2 from warlock's Spellcasting
- 2 from Bonus Cantrips
- 2 from Magic Initiate
- 1 from Spell Sniper

Since Celine also knows *wish* as a Magical Secret, she can replicate the effect of other cantrips **21 times** in one week:

- 7 times using the level 9 spell slot from her Multiclass Spellcasting
- 7 times using the level 9 spell slot from her Boon of High Magic
- 7 times using her Boon of Spell Recall

and the **last cantrip** comes from any racial trait that grants a cantrip.

That covers all 44 cantrips without even needing to worry about using *simulacrum* and *reincarnate* to rotate through the races that get other cantrips.

Comment: Way to think outside the box with epic boons. I forget those even exist. I tip my hat to you!

Comment: Yes, I wonder if there is a limited use to those epic boons ;)

Comment: @Akixkisu I did notice your comment, but had already written the answer, so I figured I'd post it. I will delete if the epic boons are banned. I'm very close to getting it without by using *simulacrum*, *reincarnate*, and *shapechange*, but not quite (although I can get all 44 with no epic boons if order doesn't matter)

Comment: I think the shifting planes one is also a good route.

Comment: I'm not planning to outright ban Boons, but it should be noted that they're pretty rare to issue, so there's definitely a potential issue with applicability. Nonetheless, this is a pretty good answer!

Answer (score 12):

Because the spell *Encode Thoughts* isn't associated with a specific class, and instead only comes from the Dimir Operative background found in Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica, it is only possible to learn the spell by taking that background. I've provided the following table as a replacement for the [answer I originally provided](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/151213/42386), which goes into more detail explaining how to get the total number of cantrips we're using.

DNDBeyond incorrectly lists the spell as a Wizard cantrip. If your table insists that DNDBeyond is correct, then you can defer to the original answer I posted. Otherwise, this answer is more correct.

#### The Character

- **Race:** High Elf
- **Background:** Dimir Operative
- **Feats**

  - *Magic Initiate [Druid]*
  - *Spell Sniper [Druid]*
- **Classes**: 18 Levels

  - **Artificer** *[Any Archetype]*: Level 10
  - **Bard**: Level 1
  - **Cleric** *[Arcana]*: Level 1
  - **Druid** *[Land]*: Level 2
  - **Sorcerer** *[Any Archetype]*: Level 1
  - **Warlock** *[Celestial]*: Level 1
  - **Wizard** *[Illusionist]*: Level 2

## Spell List (And Sources)

| **Cantrip** | **Source** | **Feature** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acid Splash | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Create Bonfire | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Dancing Lights | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Encode Thoughts | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job; Dimir Operative |
| Fire Bolt | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Frostbite | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Guidance | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Light | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Mage Hand | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Magic Stone | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Mending | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Message | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Poison Spray | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Prestidigitation | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Ray of Frost | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Resistance | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Shocking Grasp | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Spare the Dying | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Thorn Whip | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Thunderclap | Artificer | Right Cantrip for the Job |
| Blade Ward | Bard |  |
| Vicious Mockery | Bard |  |
| Gust | Cleric | Arcana |
| Infestation | Cleric | Arcana |
| Thaumaturgy | Cleric |  |
| Toll the Dead | Cleric |  |
| Word of Radiance | Cleric |  |
| Control Flames | Druid | Circle of Land (Level 2) |
| Primal Savagery | Druid |  |
| Produce Flame | Druid | Spell Sniper |
| Shape Water | Druid |  |
| Shillelagh | Druid | Magic Initiate |
| Druidcraft | Druid | Magic Initiate |
| Mold Earth | High Elf |  |
| Booming Blade | Sorcerer |  |
| Chill Touch | Sorcerer |  |
| Friends | Sorcerer |  |
| True Strike | Sorcerer |  |
| Eldritch Blast | Warlock |  |
| Green-Flame Blade | Warlock |  |
| Sacred Flame | Warlock | Celestial |
| Lightning Lure | Wizard |  |
| Minor Illusion | Wizard | Illusionist (Level 2) |
| Sword Burst | Wizard |  |

Comment: The final version of the Artificer no longer has the Right Cantrip for the Job feature, which I think might invalidate this answer

Comment: @Someone_Evil That is true, although my original question did explicitly specify that use of that class was permitted.